# How to highlighting the Latex coding in the Ms Office

Tags: microsoft-word, latex

I have a latex file.if i put those Latex content in MsOffice this want to be highlighted automatically.Like notepad++. Is there is any plugin is availabe?

Comment: Belongs here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You want to edit LaTeX in _word_!? why?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a plugin available, but I do not think it's a good idea. Word is made to work with .doc-files, and subsequently it will often insert its own markup into a file that you work on, which will mess up your tex-code. Is there a special reason you want to use Word and nothing else?

For serious work in latex, look at IDEs such as TeXniCcenter, LEd, Scientific Word (has nothing to do with word), or WinEdt.